# Slick: Dynamic sort on optionally joined table

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I'm having problem with making something like this to work:

```
implicit class MultiSortableTupledQuery3[A <: ColumnSelector, B <: ColumnSelector, C <: ColumnSelector, D, E, F](
query: slick.lifted.Query[(A, B, Rep[Option[C]]), (D, E, Option[F]), Seq]
  ) {

def dynamicSortBy(sorts: Option[InternalBlotterSort]): Query[(A, B, Rep[Option[C]]), (D, E, Option[F]), Seq] =
  sorts.foldRight(query) {
    case (sort: InternalBlotterSort, queryToSort) =>
      val sortOrderRep: slick.lifted.Rep[_] => Ordered = ColumnOrdered(_, Ordering(sort.direction))
      def sortColumnRep: ((A, B, Rep[Option[C]])) => slick.lifted.Rep[_] =
        x => (x._2.sortSelect ++ x._1.sortSelect)(sort.colId.toLowerCase)
      queryToSort.sortBy(sortColumnRep)(sortOrderRep)

  }
}
```

would like to add here something like:

```
x => (x._3.map(_.sortSelect).getOrElse(List.empty) ++ x._2.sortSelect ++ x._1.sortSelect)
```

Implementation of ColumnSelector is simple

```
trait ColumnSelector {
val sortSelect: Map[String, Rep[_]]
}
```

Slick 3.3.2 and this has become bigger and bigger problem.

In general dealing with Optional Reps but cannot remember the issue right now.

If anybody has some other suggestion how to do dynamic sorting/filtering please do tell. Using this approach we have to constantly add implicit classes and variations of Optional and non optional tables depending on the join.
This solutions work for 2 mandatory solutions joined with optional one but when you reach 5-6 table the situation gets quite messy.

Comment: Not a real answer, but we do query building dynamically, adding where and sorts with extra functions that provides extra Query Builder pieces at will, however complex you might want to make it. Should sanitize manually for sql-injection, too.

Comment: @pagoda_5b thx for the info. Do you know of any examples or blogs about the approach so I can take a look?

Comment: You might wanna check the [project source](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/Conseil/blob/master/src/main/scala/tech/cryptonomic/conseil/util/DatabaseUtil.scala) and get an idea